# Convert Dstream to Spark DataFrame using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I want to convert a `Dstream` to a `DataFrame` in order to apply same transformations on this `DataFrame` and call a `NaiveBayesModel` model to predict target probability, I use Apache Spark 2.1.1, the `Dstream` is builded from a `socketTextStream`. I tried to call a `foreachRDD` function of the `Dstream` but it dosen't work.

```
def predict(rdd):
    count = rdd.count()
    if(count>0):
        hashingTF = HashingTF(numFeatures=1000)
        features = hashingTF.transform(rdd)
        result = model.transform(features)
        return result.probability
    else:
        print("No data receveid")

model = NaiveBayesModel.load(sc, "ML_models/NaiveClassifier/naiveBayesClassifier-2010-09-10-08-51-25")
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
tweets = lines.map(lambda v: json.loads(v))
text_dstream = tweets.map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'])
df = text_dstream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: predict(rdd))
ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I get the following error message

```
AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

My idea consist of converting the `Dstream` to a Spark `DataFrame` and apply the transformation using :

```
#Tokenize sentiment text
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="SentimentText", outputCol="SetimentTextTokenize")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(df)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="SetimentTextTokenize", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=1000)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
```

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004411/create-a-dataframe-in-spark-stream

Comment: @maasg how can I do the same thing using pyspark please ? I got the following error message : `ValueError: RDD is empty`